# Blender 2.79 - grid issues!

Tags: 3d-view

I seem to be a bit confused on how to explain the current issue I am having! Overall, this happens in Blender 2.8 and higher

All I can say is that my screenshots sort of explains the issue I am having, if someone would be able to tell me how to fix it! That would be terrific

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). A quick guess - do all those objects have applied scale? Feel free to share your file https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! I did not use the scaling tool to imput the dimensions. I typed them in manually to scale the cube to what I needed for my project, the plane's are just ment to be used as a guide so that I don't go over the line after extruding the main cube once I am ready to do so to overall size of 24.4 meters (positive and negative)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out! Just had to divide the overall length by 2

Example: 24.200 m divide that by 2 = 12.100 m is where I needed to place a plane